# How can I un-till the soil in Stardew Valley?

Tags: stardew-valley

Turns out the tiles must be empty and that includes non-tilled soil if you want to build a coop or other farm buildings. Seasons just changed and I don't want to wait ~20 game days for them to change again. Is there a way to make the soil non-tilled faster?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To un-till soil just hit it with your Pickaxe.

Comment: That was so simple that I didn't even think to try it! Thanks!

Comment: Haha yea! I found out on accident myself.

Comment: Thanks. This will come in handy when I use bombs to clear the land.

Comment: that made a bit more sense in the original HM games where the pickaxe was actually a hammer lol